# How many types of cursor is supported by SQLite in Android?

Tags: android, database

I am searching lot of time and see the many database tutorials but not found how many types of cursors are supported by SQLite database.

Comment: what do you mean by "how many types of cursors support SQlite database." ?

Comment: You can check this post for more information about cursors: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html

Comment: number of interviewer Ask question this question, but i cant reply.

Comment: look at my answer. Its for android SQLite database cursors.

Comment: If you get answer from these then you should accept is as correct or up voting so we know we are going right on your question or not, or also for other user.

Answer (score 0):

these are the indirect subclasses of [android.database.Cursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) And also [android.database.CrossProcessCursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/CrossProcessCursor.html).

AbstractCursor, AbstractWindowedCursor, CrossProcessCursor, CursorWrapper, MatrixCursor, MergeCursor, MockCursor, SQLiteCursor